# wget downloads empty files even with proper referer and cookies

Tags: linux, download, shell-script, wget

I'm trying to scrape Brenda Enzymes for a bunch of molecule files with a script. If I just download by file URL (it's a PHP redirect), I get a 0Kb file, so I think they're checking for cookies and/or referer.

Then I did this:

#### 1st request

```
$ wget --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt "http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/php/search_result.php4?a=54&W%5B2%5D=&T%5B2%5D=1&Search=Search&l=100&os=1&RNV=1&RN=&T%5B0%5D=2&W%5B1%5D=3.4.21.5&T%5B1%5D=1&V%5B3%5D=1&W%5B3%5D=&T%5B3%5D=1&V%5B4%5D=1&W%5B4%5D=&T%5B4%5D=2&V%5B5%5D=1&W%5B5%5D=&T%5B5%5D=2&V%5B6%5D=1&W%5B6%5D=&T%5B6%5D=2&W%5B7%5D=&T%5B7%5D=2&FNV=1&orderDesc=1&orderByHTMLField=IC50+Value"
```

#### 2nd request

```
$ wget --referer="http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/php/search_result.php4?a=54&W%5B2%5D=&T%5B2%5D=1&Search=Search&l=100&os=1&RNV=1&RN=&T%5B0%5D=2&W%5B1%5D=3.4.21.5&T%5B1%5D=1&V%5B3%5D=1&W%5B3%5D=&T%5B3%5D=1&V%5B4%5D=1&W%5B4%5D=&T%5B4%5D=2&V%5B5%5D=1&W%5B5%5D=&T%5B5%5D=2&V%5B6%5D=1&W%5B6%5D=&T%5B6%5D=2&W%5B7%5D=&T%5B7%5D=2&FNV=1&orderDesc=1&orderByHTMLField=IC50+Value" --cookies=on --load-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt -O test.mol http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/brenda_ligand/download_ligand_molfile.php4?LigandID=298989
```

Still nothing, the resulting `test.mol` is an empty file.

However, if I follow the first URL in a browser, and then copy-n-paste the second URL, it does download an actual 3Kb-ish `.mol` file.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: testing your two wget works on my linux host... perhaps you have to delete cookies.txt ... i get a test.mo1 of 2168 Bytes.

Comment: Make sure your `cookies.txt` is blank when trying the 1st request, the existing cookie may be confusing the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do what you are attempting is to use SOAP queries. According to their [documentation](http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/soap2/index.php), the Brenda site offers SOAP functionality.

I don't know what type of information you are looking for. The following is an example of a Perl script to get the Km value for the molecule with an EC number of 1.1.1.1:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use SOAP::Lite;

$resultString = SOAP::Lite
-> uri('http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/soap2')
-> proxy('http://www.brenda-enzymes.info/soap2/brenda_server.php')
-> getKmValue("ecNumber*1.1.1.1#organism*Homo sapiens#")
-> result; 

print $resultString;
```

Have a look through the documentation, you should be able to find what you need.